# Problem with defined macro and blank lines

Tags: macros

I am using the following command to color some text:

```
{\color{NavyBlue}

Text Here!

}
```

Because I used it frequently I created this macro:

```
\def\cl#1{{\color{NavyBlue}{#1}}}
```

When I am using the first then I can have blank lines between the `{}` and the text meaning that I can do this:

```
{\color{NavyBlue}
%Blank line
%Blank line
Text!
%Blank line
%Blank line
}
```

On the other hand when I use the defined macro I can't do this as an error occurs saying "Paragraph ended before \cl was complete".

```
\cl
{
%Blank line
Text Here!
%Blank line
}
```

This is not a question regarding a solution on how to use the defined macro, as when I don't leave blank lines then it works fine. What I am asking is why is that happening and how can I define the macro to act like the command `{\color{}}`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\def\cl#1{{\color{NavyBlue}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\newcommand\cl[1]{...}` and live happy.

Comment: Or `\long\def\cl#1{{\color{NavyBlue}#1}}` to allow a paragraph break. Also `\color{NavyBlue}{#1}}` should be `\color{NavyBlue}#1}` ie, no braces around `#1`.

Comment: `\newcommand` is better in LaTeX, though, as it takes precautions which you don't get with `\def`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `\def` the arguments to the macro you define *cannot* contain `\par` (or a blank line, that's the same). This is a feature Knuth added in order to catch “runaway arguments”, that is, a forgotten closing brace around an argument.

There is an escape from this, and indeed LaTeX by default doesn't use this feature in its `\newcommand` function.

So with `\newcommand` you don't have the problem. However, your definition is not really safe:

```
\newcommand{\cl}[1]{{\leavevmode\color{NavyBlue}#1}}
```

would be much better. Note that the braces around `#1` are not necessary.

Moral of the story: ***don't*** use `\def` unless you know what you're doing and you've read chapter 20 of the TeXbook at least twice. `;-)`

Answer (score 7):

`\def` is not a latex command, you should use `\newcommand` and then blank lines (`\par`) are allowed in the argument. `\long\def` would also work, but isn't latex either.

But you may want to use

```
\textcolor{NavyBlue}{#1}
```

rather than

```
{\color{NavyBlue}{#1}}
```

as `\color` at the start of a paragraph can act in undesirable ways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it is really great. Although I chose egreg's as it is an answer best suited to my problem. :)